# Parametrize a function

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Is there any way to parametrize whereEq, so i can remove 'complete: true' and pass this information when calling the function in console log example below ?

```
let incomplete = R.filter( R.whereEq( { complete: false } ) ) 

console.log( incomplete( data ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[R.wrap](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#wrap) could be helpful here.

```
let incomplete = R.wrap(R.filter, function(filter, array, isComplete) {
  return filter( R.whereEq( { complete: isComplete }), array )
})

incomplete(data, false);
```

Comment: I've never understood the point of `R.wrap`. Here we could reference `R.filter` directly rather than providing `R.filter` to `R.wrap` and having `R.wrap` give it back to us. I've opened [ramda/ramda#1818](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1818) to deprecate `R.wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
let incomplete = (data, bool) => R.filter(R.whereEq({complete: bool}), data);
```

(although the name 'incomplete' really no longer makes sense...) ?